# iOS Simulator crashing in Virtual Machine

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator, ios6.1

I'm brand new to iOS development (and MacOS in general). While waiting for a mac to arrive I've set up a Virtual Machine running Mountain Lion to get started with developing.

When trying to run a simple Hello World application, the simulator crashes with "The simulated application quit" error message.

In the User Diagnostic Reports there is the following crash report:

```
    Process:         SpringBoard [9828]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
Identifier:      SpringBoard
Version:         2127.141
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  sim64 [9826]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2013-06-06 09:17:09.538 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8 (12A269)
Report Version:  10

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
iPhone Simulator 369.2, iPhone OS 6.1 (iPhone/10B141)


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c75a6a __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x930a0acf pthread_kill + 101
2   libsystem_sim_c.dylib           0x050fc57b abort + 140
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0500ef7b abort_message + 105
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0500ca25 default_terminate() + 34
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x04a750c1 _objc_terminate() + 94
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0500ca65 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 13
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0500cacd std::terminate() + 23
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0500dbc2 __cxa_throw + 110
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x04a74f89 objc_exception_throw + 311
10  CoreFoundation                  0x048a60de -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 158
11  MobileCoreServices              0x02f9aeaa -[LSApplicationWorkspace installedApplications] + 1095
12  SpringBoard                     0x000e1f3d 0x1000 + 921405
13  SpringBoard                     0x000e2a16 0x1000 + 924182
14  SpringBoard                     0x000df5a6 0x1000 + 910758
15  SpringBoard                     0x000df2d1 0x1000 + 910033
16  SpringBoard                     0x000df316 0x1000 + 910102
17  SpringBoard                     0x001ee6df 0x1000 + 2021087
18  SpringBoard                     0x00029040 0x1000 + 163904
19  SpringBoard                     0x00026232 0x1000 + 152114
20  SpringBoard                     0x00023b1e 0x1000 + 142110
21  SpringBoard                     0x00005479 0x1000 + 17529
22  UIKit                           0x009371af -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 354
23  UIKit                           0x009377a1 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1338
24  UIKit                           0x0093894b -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 805
25  UIKit                           0x00938086 -[UIApplication _run] + 530
26  UIKit                           0x00939ffc UIApplicationMain + 1211
27  SpringBoard                     0x00004641 0x1000 + 13889
28  SpringBoard                     0x00003a55 0x1000 + 10837

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c769ca kevent64 + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x05080c2b _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 863
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x050808cc _dispatch_mgr_thread + 61

Thread 2:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c737d2 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c72cb0 mach_msg + 68
2   liblaunch.dylib                 0x94c5ce58 0x94c59000 + 15960
3   liblaunch.dylib                 0x94c5b68e bootstrap_look_up3 + 78
4   libxpc.dylib                    0x051d5de8 _xpc_connection_bootstrap_look_up_slow + 376
5   libxpc.dylib                    0x051d6c36 _xpc_connection_init + 936
6   libxpc.dylib                    0x051d6885 _xpc_connection_resume_init + 14
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0508d014 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0507e2e8 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 335
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0507e450 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x930a1e12 _pthread_wqthread + 441
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x93089cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 3:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.MobileInstallationSetDeviceCapabilities
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c758e2 __psynch_cvwait + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x930a4220 _pthread_cond_wait + 833
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9312a0ad pthread_cond_wait$UNIX2003 + 71
3   MobileSystemServices            0x0527d083 MOXPCTransportReceiveMessage + 276
4   MobileInstallation              0x027aa015 perform_command + 682
5   MobileInstallation              0x027aabb8 __MobileInstallationSetDeviceCapabilities_block_invoke_057 + 97
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0507b53f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 15
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x0508d014 _dispatch_client_callout + 14
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x0507d418 _dispatch_queue_drain + 239
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x0507d2a6 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 59
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x0507e280 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 231
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x0507e450 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 39
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x930a1e12 _pthread_wqthread + 441
13  libsystem_c.dylib               0x93089cca start_wqthread + 30

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x93089cac start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:: WebThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c737d2 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c72cb0 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x047c4a49 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
3   CoreFoundation                  0x047c98d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
4   CoreFoundation                  0x047c8f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
5   CoreFoundation                  0x047c8e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   WebCore                         0x068cac50 RunWebThread(void*) + 608
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9309f557 _pthread_start + 344
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x93089cee thread_start + 34

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c737d2 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c72cb0 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x047c4a49 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
3   CoreFoundation                  0x047c98d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
4   CoreFoundation                  0x047c8f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
5   CoreFoundation                  0x047c8e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   Foundation                      0x0161c3ac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 298
7   Foundation                      0x0161c275 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 82
8   UIKit                           0x00cb6445 -[UIStatusBarServerThread main] + 787
9   Foundation                      0x01669764 __NSThread__main__ + 1304
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x9309f557 _pthread_start + 344
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x93089cee thread_start + 34

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c737d2 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x94c72cb0 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x047c4a49 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 185
3   CoreFoundation                  0x047c98d4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1380
4   CoreFoundation                  0x047c8f44 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 276
5   CoreFoundation                  0x047c8e1b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
6   SpringBoard                     0x000738a0 0x1000 + 469152
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x9309f557 _pthread_start + 344
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x93089cee thread_start + 34

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_c.dylib               0x93089cac start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x00000000  ebx: 0x0b1de7a0  ecx: 0xbfffe19c  edx: 0x94c75a6a
  edi: 0xac45ca28  esi: 0x00000006  ebp: 0xbfffe1b8  esp: 0xbfffe19c
   ss: 0x00000023  efl: 0x00000206  eip: 0x94c75a6a   cs: 0x0000000b
   ds: 0x00000023   es: 0x00000023   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x0000000f
  cr2: 0x05022091
Logical CPU: 0

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -   0x2acff7 +SpringBoard (2127.141) <EF39B240-01AE-3E9B-978C-B66804DCBE7B> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/CoreServices/SpringBoard.app/SpringBoard
  0x333000 -   0x3edff7 +StoreServices (858.20) <13DDADBB-7756-3DFF-8749-B978D0E9B2D5> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
  0x469000 -   0x517ff7 +CoreText (289.14) <2459B66E-179A-39B4-A9C9-8D09538B3036> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
  0x560000 -   0x6f7fff +vImage (213.5) <B0EF7ABD-F20E-3616-B8B2-BAB707710833> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
```

.....

```
External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 504
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=199.7M resident=44.0M(22%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=155.7M(78%)
Writable regions: Total=65.2M written=2516K(4%) resident=9.9M(15%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=55.3M(85%)

REGION TYPE                      VIRTUAL
===========                      =======
CoreServices                        360K
JS JIT generated code              32.0M
MALLOC                             14.0M
MALLOC guard page                    48K
Memory tag=35                      11.6M
Stack                              67.9M
VM_ALLOCATE                          64K
__DATA                             12.1M
__LINKEDIT                         70.1M
__PAGEZERO                            4K
__TEXT                            129.7M
__UNICODE                           544K
mapped file                       242.7M
shared memory                        12K
===========                      =======
TOTAL                             581.0M
```

Any help with debugging this would be great as I'm not sure where to start with fixing this.

Comment: Try to change the debugger from lldb to gdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Reset Content and Settings" resolved this issue, however I think it was combined with a step I made earlier in my attempts at debugging, as at the start I also tried resetting the contents and it didn't work...

Comment: How could you do Reset Content and Settings if the simulator crashed on launch?  Also, since you fixed it this way, you should mark your own response here as the answer so others will know the issue was solved this way.

Comment: I have to wait before I accept my answer as resolved. When the simulator crashed I had the option to 'Relaunch' after clicking this I had a few moments in which the simulator was processing and I was able to click around and reset the content.

Answer (score 1):

Can you run the simulator stand-alone, not through XCode?

If so, can you run any of the built-in applications?

I'm not sure what may be causing this but it could well be some low-level interaction between the simulator and the VM.  You should also bring up Console and see what is logged to the system when you try to run from XCode.

Comment: Running the simulator on it's own has the same out come where it crashes immediately.

The log output when loading just the simulator is here:

http://justpaste.it/2siq

However I did notice that every 10 seconds or so I've been getting an mds crash also... I'm not sure if that's related or not